# npm breeze-client + webpack + commonjs: Q is undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, breeze, q, commonjs

I am developping a react application with typescript and webpack for bundling. 
I would like to use breeze to manage my data in the client. So I go ahead and install it in my project with npm

```
npm install breeze-client --save
```

Now I create an entityManger pointing to a resource in my backend server and I execute a query. I get this error

```
Q is undefined. Are you missing Q.js? See https://github.com/kriskowal/q
```

Looking at the source code (breeze.debug.client), breeze tries to load the Q library.

```
var Q = core.requireLib("Q;q");
```

Breeze expects Q to be attached to the global window object. (see breeze.debug.js, line 423

```
function __requireLibCore(libName) {
  var window = global.window;
  if (!window) return; // Must run in a browser. Todo: add commonjs support

  // get library from browser globals if we can
  var lib = window[libName];
  if (lib) return lib;
```

I don't understand why the global.window object is undefined here. I am using webpack. Commonjs is already my module library. Elsewhere in my application I am already able to use the Q.js library without a problem (even jquery is already loaded).

Is it possible to use the npm breeze-client module in a javascript browser application with webpack+commonjs?

**Edit**

Looks like there is a [github issue here](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/119) related to using breezejs with commonjs (missing q)

Comment: I just did a test. I checked the global.window object prior to execute my query on the entityManager. The global.window object exists and it is defined. So the problem is with breeze. There must be a configuration I am missing when using webpack+breeze+commonjs.

Answer (score 0):

> Breeze expects Q to be attached to the global window object.

alright, let's tell webpack that `Q` should be available as global:

- for all modules:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Q: 'q'
      })
    ]
  };
  ```
- just for breeze:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: require.resolve('breeze-client'),
        use: 'imports-loader?window.Q=>q' // assumes Q's module name is 'q'
      }]
    }
  };
  ```

in order for this to work, you should make sure `q` is exported as global beforehand:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: require.resolve('q'),
      use: 'exports-loader?q'
    }]
  }
};
```

#### references

- [`imports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/)
- [`exports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/exports-loader/)
- [`provide-plugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)
- [shimming with webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I applied your solution. Webpack has introduced this line at the start of the breeze.debug.js file:
var window = (window || {});
window.Q = q;

Now I immediately get this error:

q is not defined

Comment: are you loading `q` first?

Comment: Although I load my modules via commonjs-require, I just included the q.js with a <script> tag in my index.html. Now the 'q is not defined' error is gone. But I am getting the original error: Q is undefined. Are you missing Q

Comment: The problem I see here is that 'core.requireLib' checks for the global.window object. Because it is undefined (I don't know why, it shouln't), it exits without setting up the Q library

Comment: No matter what I try the global object 'global.window' is undefined within the breeze.debug.js file. So 'core.requireLib' exits without loading the q library. Why global.window is undefined while in other parts of the application it is defined. I can see it in the list of all active variables via the left debug window ( I am using visual studio code)

Comment: I finally solved this problem just by calling the breeze method:

breeze.config.setQ( _my_promise_library_ );

where I can set breeze to use the promise library I pass to it

Comment: you shouldn't have to include any modules using script tags, just export Q with the exports loader instead (see the updated answer)